How to get image from HTTP payload containing Unicode characters
I have a data string of a .jpeg file that looks like this, retrieved from an HTTP Request body:
ÿØÿà\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000ÿâ\u0001ØICC_PROFILE\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0001È\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u00040\u0000\u0000mntrRGB XYZ \u0007
...

I want to save it as an image using Python (and eventually convert images back into this format).
I tried using urllib, assuming it's in base64 and UTF-8:
import urllib.request

data = u"ÿØÿà\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0001" # ...
uri = "data:image/jpeg;charset=UTF-8;base64," + data

response = urllib.request.urlopen(uri)
with open(r'image.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.file.read())

But Windows reads it as an unsupported filetype / corrupted.
Is it because of the Unicode characters? If so, how to I find the original ASCII?

Did the http response header have encoding information? Just because data, when viewed as unicode, has binary escape data doesn't mean it's unicode. BTW, that u on the front of the string is a holdover from python 2. Are you using python 3?

HTTP transports bytes. An image is binary data. You should not be trying to receive an image as text. In any case, the data: URL you have shown is malformed, as it claims the data is encoded in base64 but the data is not actually encoded in base64. Also, it makes no sense to apply UTF-8 to binary data, either.

You need to use base64 encoding of the URI; this is specified in the base64, prefix before the data.
import base64

uri = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64.b64encode(data)


You should also get rid of the charset as it does not apply to image media types. It also doesn't make sense to store image data in a Unicode string to begin with. Base64 encodes bytes, not strings.
